# Looping through a string without VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say I have a string that will always be binary, and inputted in cell E3 such as:

"cat, cat, dog"

and I wanted to apply an IF statement to this, so

IF(E3 = 'cat', 1, 0)

is there a way for me to make the above if statement work for a string without using VBA? Maybe something to tell it to test for any characters before or after the ','? Additionally, the if statement would ideally be applied through 3 cells, so it would look like:

```
1
1
0
```

Could I make use of the RC method in Excel?

Comment: What does "IF(E3 = 'cat', 1, 0)" mean? Are you trying to check that E3 is only "cat, cat, cat..." - i.e. no "dog" in the string?

Comment: Goal is something like to be able to write in column F- "buy" if the value in column E is cat, and "sell" if the value is dog. I wanted to loop through each cell in E to write a corresponding value in B without using VBA to do this, so I thought if I made all the values in column E a string, and then checked did the method above it might work?

Comment: So you have values going down column E? And if the value is "cat", you want B to say "buy", otherwise "sell"? Your description is very confusing.

Comment: Happy to provide more clarification - but yes, that's the goal, not sure if this is possible without VBA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a little tricky to get it to work for variable/unequal string lengths. Refer to the image below. I entered this as an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) in `B4:B9`:

```
=1-MOD(SMALL(IF(MID(B1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B1))),LEN(B2))=B2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B1))),IF(MID(B1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B1))),LEN(B3))=B3,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B1)))+0.5)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&INT(LEN(B1)/MIN(LEN(B2),LEN(B3)))+1))),1)*2
```

[image]

Comment: That is some seriously good formula action. I might even get it printed on a t shirt! :0)